# What is the difference between updateQueryData() and patchQueryData() in Redux Toolkit Query?

Tags: api, caching, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Why do we need the API patchQueryData() in Redux Toolkit Query?

I can't see how it is different from updateQueryData() on [the official documentation here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#patchquerydata).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`patchQueryData` applies an "immer patch" to the cache entry, while `updateQueryData` allows you to run a function against your cache entry and just "change" it. Internally, that will create a patch and then call `updateQueryData`. So, essentially `patchQueryData` is an implementation detail. It will not be useful for most people, but some people might see benefit in it, so it is exposed as well.

Comment: What is an "immer patch"? How is it different from just "changing it"?

Comment: An `immer patch` is an object describing a change that should be made.  See https://immerjs.github.io/immer/patches/ for a few examples on how those patches can look like. Usually you would not use `patchQueryData` by hand.